# Java Web Development and Automatic Feedback

Tags: java, playframework

I've been having a (ironic) play around with the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org) and have been impressed thus far.  I was just curious as to what other Java frameworks are out there that have a similar feature to Play in that you are able to get immediate feedback when making changes to your code base without having to re-build or re-deploy your app?

Comment: Do you mean other Java frameworks or more generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "immediate feedback" (see changes without lengthy rebuild and redeploy) part, I've used [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) with some decent success.  Definitely worth a look.